# "high building" vs. "tall building"

Tags: word-usage

[An ELU post says](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/152362)

> You wouldn't generally call a building high.

I believe that is correct for most of the case. For instance, this one is correct

> The Statue of Liberty is as tall as 93 m

while this one sounds unnatural.

> The Statue of Liberty is as **high** as 93 m

---

However, [Ngram Viewer shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20highest%20building%2C%20the%20tallest%20building&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cthe%20highest%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20highest%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20highest%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cthe%20tallest%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20tallest%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20tallest%20building%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cthe%20highest%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20highest%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20highest%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cthe%20tallest%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20tallest%20building%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BThe%20tallest%20building%3B%2Cc0) both "high" and "tall" could be used for building.

[image]

Some of the Google search recommendations are

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: @Princesadh That is exact the one I linked in OP.

Comment: That looks about right:  "The tallest building" is about 10 times more common than "the highest building".  Both are correct grammar (and mean the same), but you wouldn't generally call a building high.  90% of the time you call it tall.

Comment: Out of context, I would take "highest building" to refer to the highest building above sea level which is isn't the same as tallest building, which would be the height from ground level to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is that? Well, it's just what people are searching on Google. It's not meant to tell you what is "correct" or "incorrect".

I also saw this question on EL&U. To me, it's a very interesting question: I never even thought about the difference between "high" and "tall" until I read it. I agree with the sentiments expressed in the comments that a building would generally be referred to as being **tall** as opposed to *high*.

When I was searching this topic, I found the following:

> When things are higher than they are wide, we say tall. People are higher than they’re wide, so we talk about tall people ... When things are shorter than they’re wide, we say ‘high’.
>   https://www.simpleenglishvideos.com/high-tall/

I guess this explains why calling buildings "tall" is more common.

Just a quick note: in your example sentences, I think it would be better to say

> The Statue of Liberty **is 93 m tall**.

simply because it's a description of its height, as opposed to a comparison.